# Indextable numbering space

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer, table-of-contents

There is no space between the outline numbering and the TEXT in my Table of Contents.
My heading styles 1 - 3 have bullets_and_numbering/position/minimum_space_numbering<->text 0,38cm but the Outline numbering CONTENTS X styles  does not follow the HEADING X styles .

How can I control the spaces between the numbering and text in the Table of Contents?

Comment: What application?

Comment: Sorry Open Office Writer

Comment: I got tired of playing arround and copied the text to a template